# How to check whether buttons are pressed in the correct order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In my project, I want to check whether the buttons are pressed in the correct sequence or not. The correct sequence is stored in an array.
For that, I added an event listener using a for loop and created a separate function for the event listener. But the function is not getting executed while running the loop, only giving an alert without clicking on the button. Here is the code :

```
    var points = [1,2,3,4,5];
    
    for(var j=0;j<points.length;j++)
    {
      checkButton(j);
    }
    
    
    function checkButton(j)
    {
      $("button").on("click", function(){
        if($(this).text()== points[j] )
        {
          alert("compleated step "+(j+1));
        }
        else
        {
          alert("incorrect step "+(j+1));
        }
      });
    }
```

Thanks for your time !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to your for-loop you are registering the same event-handler multiple times. All you need to do is to register the click-handler once and adjust the logic of checking wheter the buttons are pressed in the correct order.

You should consider using the value attribute to assign each button a value as this allows you to  uncouple the value from the text.

HTML

```
<div>
  <p>Click buttons in correct sequence!</p>
  <button value="1">#1</button>
  <button value="2">#2</button>
  <button value="3">#3</button>
  <button value="4">#4</button>
  <button value="5">#5</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
var order = [2,4,1,3,5]
var nextOrderIndex = 0;
// register handler once
$("button").on("click", function() {
  // parse text of button to int for correct comparison
  var buttonValue = parseInt($(this).attr("value"))
  if (buttonValue == order[nextOrderIndex]) {
    // count up for next check
    // use modulo to start back at 0 when counter reaches order.length
    nextOrderIndex = (nextOrderIndex + 1) % order.length;
    alert("Correct");
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect");
  }
});
```

See working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsg057Lm/22/)

Edit:
adjusted for random order

Comment: the order in the array can change, it can be 3,2,4,2,1 or anything else. I took 1,2,3,4,5 just for example.

Comment: i adjusted my answer to account for any random order